# JSP not returning data to JQuery AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Here is my function. I am trying to get the data from the JSP page below. Both files are at the same location. What is my mistake?

**`sample.js`(included in some file):**

```
function getUnits(){
 $.ajax({

url:"../js/addunits.jsp",
success: function(returndata){
    alert(returndata);
}
});
}
```

**JSP Page `addunits.jsp`:**

```
 <%
     out.print("hi");
 >%
```

In a HTML page, I have a select list.
On change, this function `getunits` will be called.

```
    $("#select").change(function() {
    getUnits();
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var SelValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('crs').innerHTML = SelValue;
});
```

Comment: where do you call `addunits()`? Have you used browser console to check for errors and to see if request is being made?

Comment: What is a status after you call it?

Comment: i have checked. no clues.

Comment: what does `no clues` mean? To me that implies the requests are made and the expected data is returned

Comment: i mean the console doesn't show any errors. i'm not sure the request was made. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: I just want the jsp code to be executed and the result is to be returned via ajax.

Comment: Finally, figured it out. How foolish of me. The mistake is in jsp page-addunits.jsp  - closing tag issue.
<%
     out.print("hi");
%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to flush a buffer.

```
<%
 out.print("hi");
 out.flush();
%>
```

**EDIT:**

It was an assumption at the first place in case if you have a success status code for the ajax call and it might be in particular scenario like yours but not in all cases because if you used that javascript *included in some file*, then you might make the same mistake twice. When building some URL on the page  don't use a relative path in the code, especially if the page is dispatched/included from different places. Next in the absolute path you should include a context path either `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` or use JSTL's `<c:url>` tag. You can do it for loading `sample.js` but not inside it because you can use the JSP stuff only on JSP page. So, you can build the URL in the JSP and pass it as parameter to js function like that

**`sample.js`:(included in some file)**

```
function getUnits(theUrl){
 $.ajax({

   url: theUrl,
   success: function(returndata){
     alert(returndata);
   }
 });
}
```

So, in JSP page (you should use `jsp` folder where you should keep JSP pages) use

```
<script>
  ...
  getUnits('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/addunits.jsp');
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: actually jsp is not returning anything. I want to know the reason.

Comment: the data is too small, less than a buffer size isn't sent with response until the buffer is flushed.

Comment: @RomanC Please edit your answer to include that information as people frequently don't read the comments. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot @RomanC. the information helped me. but I found the mistake which is closing tag misspelt as >% istead of %>.

Comment: It was a typo, just removed it.